# Pause kafka read in reactive Kafka

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor, reactor-kafka

I have an application that reads from kafka using reactive kafka. Below is the code to read from kafka:

```
public Flux<String> readFromKafka() {
        return kafkaConsumerTemplate
                .receiveAutoAck()
                .doOnNext(consumerRecord -> log.debug("received key={}, value={} from topic={}, offset={}",
                        consumerRecord.key(),
                        consumerRecord.value(),
                        consumerRecord.topic(),
                        consumerRecord.offset())
                )
                .doOnNext(s-> processData(s))
                .map(ConsumerRecord::value)
                .doOnNext(c -> log.debug("successfully consumed c{}", c))
                .doOnError(exception -> log.error("Error occurred while processing the message, attempting retry. Error message: {} {}", exception.getMessage(), exception))
                .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(Integer.parseInt(retryAttempts), Duration.ofSeconds(Integer.parseInt(retryAttemptsDelay))).transientErrors(true))
                .onErrorResume(exception -> {
                    log.error("Kafka read retries exhausted : {} {}",exception.getMessage(), exception.toString());
                    return Flux.empty();
                });
    }
```

I have a requirement wherein I need to pause this read at a scheduled time for a task to process something and resume after the task is complete. This is the code I have added

```
   public void pauseKafkaRead() {
        List<TopicPartition> list = kafkaConsumerTemplate.assignment().collectList().block();
        for (TopicPartition partition: list){
            log.info("Partition: " + partition.toString());
            kafkaConsumerTemplate.pause(partition);
        }
    }

    public void resumeKafkaRead() {
        List<TopicPartition> list = kafkaConsumerTemplate.assignment().collectList().block();
        for (TopicPartition partition: list) {
            log.info("Partition: " + partition.toString());
            kafkaConsumerTemplate.resume(partition);
        }
    }
```

I call the pauseKafkaRead() method when I start with the task and call resume once the task is complete.
However, this doesn't seem to pause the read. The data is continued to be read from Kafka and processed. Would someone be able to help me understand what I am missing here?

Comment: You don't really need to pause kafka consumer explicitly. The latest version have a built-in mechanism for pausing to handle backpreasure.  In case processing of polled messages is taking too long - `reactor-kafka` would pause consumer until messages are processed. 
For example we used this behavior to implement "delayed consumer" to process messages with a defined delay.

Comment: Thanks for replying Alex. My requirement is that I need to explicitly stop the kafka read at  a scheduled time for example once a day to do another process outside of kafka read (readFromKafka ())and resume once that process is complete. I don't think I can use backpressure feature for that, please let me know if I am wrong

Comment: As an idea, you could periodically check time while processing records and then use `Mono.delay()` to stop processing. As result, consumer will be paused. As far as I know the only way to pause it explicitly - use `doOnConsumer` API (https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/milestone/api/reactor/kafka/receiver/KafkaReceiver.html#doOnConsumer-java.util.function.Function-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kafka on pause or resume is offering you a mono so you need to subscribe in that stream in order to make it execute.
You can try like this

```
  public void pauseKafkaRead() {
    kafkaConsumerTemplate.assignment()
        .flatMap(o -> kafkaConsumerTemplate.pause(o))
        .subscribe();

  }
  public void resumeKafkaRead() {
    kafkaConsumerTemplate.assignment()
        .flatMap(o -> kafkaConsumerTemplate.resume(o))
        .subscribe();
  }
```